# Form does not display form errors in template

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1

For my contact form no form errors are displayed.

```
    $contact = new Contact();

    $form = $this->createForm(new ContactFormType(), $contact);

    /* handle contact form submission */
    if ('POST' == $request->getMethod()) {
        $form->bindRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            //Do something
        }
    }

    return $this->render('MainBundle:Default:contact.html.twig', array(
                'form' => $form->createView()
    ));
```

My validator

```
Fc\MainBundle\Entity\Contact:
    properties:
        firstName:
            - NotBlank: ~

        lastName:
            - NotBlank: ~

        email:
            - NotBlank: ~
            - Email:
                checkMX: true
        title:
            - NotBlank: ~
        message:
            - NotBlank: ~
```

I have added a novalidate attribute to my form tag to check if my validation works. Now when I submit the form with empty data nothing happens (with correct data everything is fine), the controller identifies the form as invalid and stops further processes.

In the template I call

```
 {{ form_errors(form) }}
```

But nothing is displayed. Any ideas why? I use symfony 2.1.X

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you confirm that the validation is working with this:

```
if ($form->isValid()) {
//Do something
}
else
{ die('not valid') }
```

Is the form well posted?

Is there anything in the HTML that shows up where you call  {{ form_errors(form) }} ? - it would be a CSS or JS problem if that's the case...

Have you tried to show the errors by field (there is no global error in your validation apparently):

```
{{ form_errors(form.firstName) }}
etc.
```

Remark: **form.firstName** works, not **form.first_name**. You have to follow that convention with Doctrine2/Symfony2.

Comment: +1 Your last point...it shows the error message for the firstName field or any single field. But form_errors(form) does not work. I need form_errors(form) to work

Comment: can't remember the syntax then but basically, you just need to loop on all the form errors... have a look in the API. Probably something like $errors = $form->getErrors() and use that in the template (for error in errors ... error.message)

Comment: $form->getErrors() returns empty array

Comment: In the API: https://github.com/symfony/Form/blob/master/FormView.php ... FormView implements IteratorAggregate which means you can do {% for raw in form %} . form_errors(form) display global errors. form_errors(raw) should do.

Comment: Strange, but I have the opposite problem. {{ form_errors(form) }} shows all form errors properly, but when I want to display an individual field error like {{ form_errors(form.first_name) }}, nothing shows. Can that be related? Thanks!

Comment: I found out the answer to my problem. Symfony2 doesn't like "_" underscores in field names. I had to follow the camel convention and change it to firstName. Now it works for individual fields.

Comment: Obvious now that you say it ^^ - I'll edit my answer for others.

Comment: +1 for your Remark about form.firstName and not form.first_name

Comment: {{ form_errors(customerForm.address2) }} it does not show anything..any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: there is a first parameter to getErrors() which is deep = true or false. It returns all errors cummulated in all children, or nested (if second parameter is false)