# Symfony2 form validation does not work

Tags: php, forms, validation, symfony

I trying to validate the Symfony2 form. But nor of these ways not works:

```
{{ form_errors(form) }}
```

and

```
{{ form_errors(form.field1) }}
{{ form_errors(form.field2) }}
```

Where can be my problem ? 
I try to find solution but i didnt ge any results. Help please.

Related posts, here :

[Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26398988/symfony-2-form-validation)

[Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13819319/form-does-not-display-form-errors-in-template)

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me.

Inside your bundle `your bundle name/Resource/config/validation.yml` you need to add the error message you want displayed for example this is what my contact form `validation.yml` looks like

```
    properties:
        name:
          - NotBlank: {message: "Please provide your name"}
        email:
          - NotBlank: {message: "Please provide youe email"}
          - Email:
                      message: '"{{ value }}" is not valid.'
        comment:
          - NotBlank: {message: "Please enter your comment"}
```

Then inside your twig to display a message for lets say the name field,

```
{% if(form_errors(form.name)) %}
{{ form_errors(form.name) }}
{% endif %}
```

Inside your controller you need to place a check

```
if ($form->isValid()) {....your processing code here }
```

Finally in your `app/config/config.yml` enable validation

```
framework:
    validation:      { enabled: true, enable_annotations: false }
```

Comment: hello, thanks but it didn help for me... i dont know where is the problem, in logs i see the errors messages, but `{{ form_errors(..)}}` return empty string...